# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking

I am setting up a test that should expect calls on two "subscriber" instances:

```
  it "sends out sms to all the subscribers" do
    @user.subscribers.create!
    @user.subscribers.create!

    Subscriber.any_instance.should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).times(2)
    post :create, {:broadcast => valid_attributes}   
  end
```

The actual code is:

```
  def create
    @broadcast = Broadcast.new(params[:broadcast])
    current_user.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
      subscriber.send_message(@broadcast.message)
    end

    ...
```

The error:

```
  Failure/Error: post :create, {:broadcast => valid_attributes}
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./app/controllers/broadcasts_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
     # ./app/controllers/broadcasts_controller.rb:40:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/broadcasts_controller_spec.rb:73:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

For some reason, if I add the line:         `Subscriber.any_instance.should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).times(2)`, it fails with that error message. If I remove that line, the test runs smoothly (no wrong number of argument problem). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try: `Subscriber.any_instance.should_receive(:send_message).twice.with(@message)`

Comment: ah thanks - almost worked. Still get:
 Failure/Error: post :create, {:broadcast => valid_attributes}
       The message 'send_message' was received by #<Subscriber id: 2, name: nil, number: nil, created_at: "2012-09-04 19:0
6:52", updated_at: "2012-09-04 19:06:52", user_id: 1> but has already been received by #<Subscriber:0x007fb48b121230>

Comment: I fear you should mock every subscriber then.

Comment: but how do i mock every subscriber? i tried that, but the instance of subscriber to which a call is made is a new instance (since the instance is created when it is fetched from the db)

Comment: first mock `current_user` then stub `subscribers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because the 'times' method is expected to be chained onto one of the other "receive count" expectations. You can use any one of the following:

```
should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).exactly(2).times
should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).at_most(2).times
```

You can also use one of the other alternatives that does not require the 'times' method:

```
should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).twice
should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).at_most(:twice)
```

More on that can be found in the [rspec-mocks documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames)

You may need to set the expectation BEFORE creating the subscribers:

```
it "sends out sms to all the subscribers" do
  Subscriber.any_instance.should_receive(:send_message).with(@message).twice

  @user.subscribers.create!
  @user.subscribers.create!

  post :create, {:broadcast => valid_attributes}   
end
```